# Unable to return ordered result from django model

Tags: django, model, sql-order-by

I have defined (django version 1.6) a model and try to order by the content based on the name variable but it seems it doesn't return an ordered result:

```
class Region(MPTTModel):

  code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)
    verbose_name_plural = 'Metadata Regions'

  class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

The result is shown in a many2many django form, which is defined as:

```
regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region, verbose_name=_('keywords region'), blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I use a rather old django version: 1.6.

Comment: Please post the model that contains "regions" field, and your query.